# Why is my code broken?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I'm making a page that has javascript bubble links and I want a slideshow on it. It seemed to work fine, but then after making a couple other pages with slideshows, they all broke. I'm not sure why because they all have different names with different javascripts and they're all in the right place. I'm going to paste all the code I have for one page. I have a folder named jewelry that has the pictures and the javascript, however the html page is in the main folder, but I have it labeled as such. Is there something that I'm missing or need to take away? I'd like to note that the javascript  got is pretyy much completely from a javascript book ( I just changed the file locations and the captions) so that should be pretty good. It's mostly the html. I want my navigation to work with my slideshow. It'll show the first image, but then the buttons won't go to the next slide.

If you have any suggestions for easier coding, go ahead. Otherwise, I'd just like to get this fixed. My final project is due in a couple days and idk how to fix this! I don't have it all uploaded to an actual link so you'll have to work with the snippets I gave you - which is literally my whole entire page and all my javascript.

Thanks in advance.

```js
window.onload = initAll;

var currImg = 0;
var captionText = [
 "Mostly bracelets right now",
];

function initAll() {
 document.getElementById("imgText").innerHTML = captionText[0];
 document.getElementById("prevLink").onclick = function() {
  newSlide(-1);
 }
 document.getElementById("nextLink").onclick = function() {
  newSlide(1);
 }
}

function newSlide(direction) {
 var imgCt = captionText.length;

 currImg = currImg + direction;
 if (currImg < 0) {
  currImg = imgCt-1;
 }
 if (currImg == imgCt) {
  currImg = 0;
 }
 document.getElementById("slideshow1").src = "jewelry/bracelet" + currImg + ".jpg";
 document.getElementById("imgText").innerHTML = captionText[currImg];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Think Jewelry</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, circular menu, navigation, round, bubble"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <script src="jewelry/jewelry.js"></script>
        <style>
          #horizon        
     {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    
   }

   #stuff    
    {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
   background-color: #fff;
   margin-left: -500px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -125px;
   left: 50%;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 450px;
   visibility: visible;
   overflow: scroll;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 5px dotted #F3DECD;
   text-align: center;
   }
   
   footer {
    height:45px;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#EAC5E4;
   position:relative;
   bottom:-0;
   font-style: italic;
   }
   
     *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            body{
                font-family:Arial;
    background:#fff url(images/bg1.png) repeat;
    background-size: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
                
            }
            .title{
                width:548px;
                height:119px;
                position:absolute;
                background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
            }

            #content{
                margin:0 auto;
            }
   

        </style>
    </head>

    <body> 
 
        <div id="content">
  <a href="index.html"><div class="title"> </div></a>

            <div class="navigation" id="nav">
                <div class="item user">
                    <img src="images/bg_user.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>Home</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="aboutshop.html">About the Shop</a></li>
       <li><a href="aboutartist.html">About the Artist</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item home">
                    <img src="images/bg_home.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>How-To's</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="howtojewelry.html">Jewelry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="howtoclay.html">Clay</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item shop">
                    <img src="images/bg_shop.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="jewelry.html">Jewelry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="clay.html">Clay</a></li>
                        <li><a href="digital.html">Digital</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="item camera">
                    <img src="images/bg_camera.png" alt="" width="199" height="199" class="circle"/>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <ul>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Questions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#nav > div').hover(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                        'width'     :'199px',
                        'height'    :'199px',
                        'top'       :'-25px',
                        'left'      :'-25px',
                        'opacity'   :'1.0'
                    },500,'easeOutBack',function(){
                        $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(700);
                    });

                    $this.find('a:first,h2').addClass('active');
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.find('ul').fadeOut(500);
                    $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                        'width'     :'52px',
                        'height'    :'52px',
                        'top'       :'0px',
                        'left'      :'0px',
                        'opacity'   :'0.1'
                    },5000,'easeOutBack');

                    $this.find('a:first,h2').removeClass('active');
                }
            );
            });
   
        </script>
  
  
  
  
<div id="horizon">
 <div id="stuff">
 <h2> Jewelry Gallery </h2><br>

  <img src="jewelry/bracelet0.jpg" alt="My Jewelry" id="slideshow1"></img>
 <div id="imgText"> </div>
 <div id="chgImg">

  <input type="button" id="prevLink" value="&laquo; Previous">
  <input type="button" id="nextLink" value="Next &raquo;">

 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<footer>

<a href="http://kiya-rose.deviantart.com/">
 <img height="32" width="32" alt=" Deviantart" src="deviantart.png">  
 </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thinkjewelryy">
 <img height="32" width="32" alt=" Think Jewelry Page" src="facebook.png"> 
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Copyright&copy; Brittany Rose
</footer>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the desired functionality and what goes wrong? Are there any errors in your browsers javascript console?

Comment: We need your url or source have real url.We can't check source of  your snippet

Comment: Please create a reduced, simplified, much shorter version of your code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why "CaptionText" array has just one single item in it? In this case your slide index always will be "0".

> var captionText = [
>       "Mostly bracelets right now",
>   ];

Comment: So how can I make the javascript different where it will be the same caption but I can still scroll through the images?